# AttributeError: the object 'TeleBot' does not have the attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python, telegram-bot

When I run the code I get the following response:

> AttributeError: the object 'TeleBot' does not have the attribute 'message_handler'.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# This is a simple echo bot using the decorator mechanism.
# It echoes any incoming text messages.

import telebot

API_TOKEN = 'my Private code'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

# Handle '/start' and '/help'
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, """\
Hi there, I am EchoBot.
I am here to echo your kind words back to you. Just say anything nice and I'll say the exact same thing to you!\
""")

# Handle all other messages with content_type 'text' (content_types defaults to ['text'])
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the telebot library uses `MessageHandler`, not message_handler. here is the [documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.messagehandler.html)